# Rails - Using omniauth-saml with multiple IDPs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth, saml

What I'm trying to have in the end is the ability to login normally with devise OR choose to login with SAML. So I read that if I integrate omniauth and saml, then omniauth and devise, I could achieve that.

My problem is, that I have different IDPs that I would like to choose from. So I don't have one :idp_sso_target_url, but many. So my question is how can I dynamically change the value of the target_url. Currently the omniauth-saml gem defines this value in the config/initializers directory..

Answer (score 6):

You can store settings for every provider in db, and then configure omniauth in the setup phase at request-time. For example:

```
SETUP_PROC = lambda do |env| 
  request = Rack::Request.new(env)
  user = User.find_by_subdomain(request.subdomain)
  env['omniauth.strategy'].options[:consumer_key] = user.consumer_key
  env['omniauth.strategy'].options[:consumer_secret] = user.consumer_secret
end

use OmniAuth::Builder.new do
  provider :twitter, :setup => SETUP_PROC
end
```

See https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki/Setup-Phase for more information.

Answer (score 5):

Using multiple SAML IDPs with Devise + OmniAuth:

Follow this official guide for Single IDP.

https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth-saml#devise-integration

Once you have your SP working with single IDP, do following tweaks

1. In `devise` initializer

   ```
   config.omniauth :first, {
                             name: :first,
                             strategy_class: ::OmniAuth::Strategies::SAML,
                             #Rest of the config as per omniauth-saml guide  
                             assertion_consumer_service_url: '/users/auth/first/callback'}



   config.omniauth :second, {
                              name: :second,
                              strategy_class: ::OmniAuth::Strategies::SAML,
                              #Rest of the config as per omniauth-saml guide
                              assertion_consumer_service_url: '/users/auth/second/callback'}
   ```
2. In `Users::OmniauthCallbacksController`, add actions named `first` and `second` in  instead of `saml` as suggested in official guide.
3. In your `User` model:

   ```
   devise :omniauthable, omniauth_providers: [:first, :second]
   ```

If all configured correctly, you now have your SP configured for two IDPs.

Answer (score 3):

```
 Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
   provider :saml,
     name: "first",
     assertion_consumer_service_url: "/auth/first/callback",
     issuer: "your-app",
     idp_sso_target_url: "first.com/idp"
     idp_cert_fingerprint: "E7:91:B2:E1:...",
     name_identifier_format: "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress"
   provider :saml,
     name: "second",
     assertion_consumer_service_url: "/auth/second/callback",
     issuer: "your-app",
     idp_sso_target_url: "second.com/idp",
     idp_cert_fingerprint: "E7:91:B2:E1:...",
     name_identifier_format: "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress"

 end
```

Answer (score 0):

If using the application in a federation context there will be most likely a metadata source, such as prescribed in the saml2int.org profile. This metadata has the data to populate IDP discovery (and automatically configure all the IDPs). It seems that omniauth-saml does not support the SAML Metadata specification, therefore some kind of SAML proxy is the alternative.